# Error despues de añadir mi propio framework a un proyecto

Tags: swift, xcode

Acabo de agregar mi frameworj personalizado a un proyecto. Estoy usando Swift 4 y la última versión de Xcode.

Cuando quiero compilar mi proyecto con el framework interno, el compilador no reconoce ninguna clase del framework en el mismo framework.

Aquí os dejo el mensaje de error: `Use of undeclared type 'EngineCrypto'`. He buscado aquí en Stack una situación similar, pero no hubo suerte.

Comment: ayudarían mas si pones un poco de código. Con lo que aportas solo te puedo responder que el tipo EngineCrypto no esta declarado

Comment: @Spidvmp ya lo he solucionado, gracias por tu atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he solucionado el error. Simplemente mi proyecto no tenia acceso al framework.

Para añadir correctamente un custom framework, en esta web esta perfectamente explicado:

[https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorialhttps://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorialhttps://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial)